# Create an internal alias to external service with istio

Tags: security, kubernetes, istio

Using istio is it possible to make an internal alias to a service outside the service mesh that was defined using a `ServieEntry` and control access to the external service?

For example suppose I have a service entry

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: mypgsql
  namespace: externalapps
spec:
  hosts:
  - mypgsql.example.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 5432
    protocol: TCP
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
  namespace:  externalapps
spec:
  selector:
  ... How would I select the service entry ...
```

Can I create another service entry or some other resource in an app namespace that references the mypsql service entry

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: dbsvc
  namespace: someapp
spec:
  hosts:
  - mypsql.externalapps
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 5432
    protocol: TCP
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-db
  namespace:  someapp
spec:
  selector:
  ... How would I select the dbsvc service entry ...
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-backend-to-db
  namespace:  someapp
spec:
  selector:
  ... How would I select the dbsvc service entry ...
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
     - source:
         principals:
         - app_backend
```